# CSV "Multi-line field with double-quotes" does not detect end-line properly - PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to upload csv file data, using the below code to get the data of csv (semi-colon separated) file.

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";"))
```

CSV Data :

```
Adresse postale;Adresse RDV;Date de naissance madame;Date de naissance monsieur;
127 Rue Victor Hugo;127 Rue Victor Hugo;"Phoniste : rachel TONDY
Agent : BERNAD Clément";appel du 17/02/09;
```

FgetCSV Output :

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(64) "127 Rue Victor Hugo;127 Rue Victor Hugo;"Phoniste : rachel TONDY" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(42) "Agent : BERNAD Clément";appel du 17/02/09;" }
```

fgetcsv returns two separate array instead of one row. I have used 
`ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);`

this line but I am not getting the expected result

Comment: this is not valid csv. new line in csv = next row

Comment: you could try to fix it by looking for a \n within "... preg_replace()

Answer (score 0):

The semi-colon inside the double quote is not considered as a delimiter.

So the second row and third row only has one element when parsed to an array as csv.